# Display Messages in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3 Razor for my website. My requirement is that I want to show display friendly messages to the user on Success/Failure of the request, on the View itself, don't want to re direct the user to another View. I want like I could customize the display like Green color with some Success image and Red color for failure and respective image.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: It's a bit unspecific. What do you already have?

Comment: I'm interested in best practices for *where* the code should be. For example, you can return a JavaScriptResult from your action method (`return this.JavaScript(@"jQuery('#foo').fadeIn(2000).delay(10000).fadeOut(5000);");`) or you can use events from an AJAX request. But ultimately you need code somewhere that shows and hides the message. The code is somewhat specific to the view, but embedding JavaScript in a view seems to be mixing responsibilities of controller and view... Perhaps you should have a global JS file with a very specific function or method to call for this view..?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know if a request failed or succeeded based on user input. If you are posting data to the server, you want to consider using the `AjaxHelper` the `BeginForm`-method takes an argument of `AjaxOptions`.

On the `AjaxOptions` you can specify OnSuccess and OnError among others and when one of these are called, you can call the corresponding JavaScript.

If this on the other hand is not enough, you might want to inspect the data that came from the server and based on that decide if the request succeeded or not, you want to use `jQuery` and their ajax-components. [Here's an example of how to use the `jQuery`-option:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("/MyController/MyAction", function(data) {
   // Check what data contains.
 });
```

Comment: Well I am not using Ajax calls every where. Lets take a simple example I have a Registration Form say the data was not saved to database (server side call to Action in my controller) basically form is posted back. The response is Registration failed due to say email id already registered. This I want to show to the user.

Comment: You can do this the way I described above and you can also use data-annotations. Check this article out: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs  you should also read this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx this should get you going, tell me if you still can't solve it!

Comment: I believe my requirement is perceived in some other way. I just want to show say " Record added successfully" to my user.

Comment: Then you should use `AjaxOptions` and use the `OnSuccess`-event and fire a JavaScript accordingly. Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200960/asp-net-mvc-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-fires-too-early

Comment: @vivek, did it turn out as you'd like?