# ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.ActionLink AjaxOptions UpdateTargetId happened before or after OnSuccess callback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering if the after the controller method returns a partial view, the runtime will updatetargetid first or call onsuccess callback function first?

Comment: I guess updatetargetid will go first, but I am not very sure about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that. See [following post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200960/asp-net-mvc-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-fires-too-early)

I think best way is to use jquery ajax to make sure of the process order.

Comment: well, is there a reason that the order is not guaranteed, what is the design purpose of the onsuccess option and updatetargetid....

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I just referred you to a post that showed the order is sometimes not what you expected