# MVC4 - Register is partial view but on success should Redirect to a new Full Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Partial View for Register.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", 
                       new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", 
                                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                         UpdateTargetId = "loginForm" }))
```

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           Guid activationGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
           if (UserManager.Register(model.Email, model.FullName, model.Password, activationGUID))
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
           else
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "This email already exists");
        }

        return PartialView(model);
  }
```

**On error**,
I want the partial view to show the error message
The controller calls **return PartialView(model);** ...and that works !!!

**On success**,
I want the entire page to refresh (instead than the UpdateTargetId specified on the ajax call).
The controller calls **return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");** ...and that fails !!!

Instead I'm getting the Dashboard form inserted into the UpdateTargetID.
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OnSuccess` method and choose if you want to replace `div` content or change `window.location`

Comment: Look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200960/asp-net-mvc-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-fires-too-early