# Filling Select2 Dropdown using ASP.net MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to fill a dropdown which use Select2 Jquery add-on using asp.net mvc4. I have already search the stackoverflow and found the related topic as below ;

[Fill Select2 dropdown box from database in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853643/fill-select2-dropdown-box-from-database-in-mvc-4)

But in my project i cant get this work.

**In my View**

```
<div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Proje Adı</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                 <select id="PROJECTID">

                                     </select>
                                 </div>
</div>
```

`In my controlle`r i wrote my action which returns the JSON and i have tested this action with manuel entries and **it is OK**. I can see the JSON result.

```
  public JsonResult FetchItems(string query)
        {
            List<CRM_PROJECTS> projectList = db.CRM_PROJECTS.Where(p => p.IS_VALID == 1 && p.NAME != null).ToList(); //fetch list of items from db table
            List<CRM_PROJECTS> resultProjectList = new List<CRM_PROJECTS>(); //create empty results list
            foreach (var item in projectList)
            {
                //if any item contains the query string
                if (item.NAME.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    resultProjectList.Add(item); //then add item to the results list
                }
            }
            //resultProjectList.Sort(delegate(Item c1, Item c2) { return c1.ItemName.CompareTo(c2.ItemName); }); //sort the results list alphabetically by ItemName
            var serialisedJsonProjects = from result in resultProjectList //serialise the results list into json
                select new
                {
                    name = result.NAME, //each json object will have 
                    id = result.ID      //these two variables [name, id]
                };
            return Json(serialisedJsonProjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //return the serialised results list
        }
```

In the select2.js file i have implemented the Jquery part of code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PROJECTID").select2({

            placeholder: "Type to find a Contract",
            allowClear: true,
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax:{ 
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                url: "/AddNewOpp/FetchItems",               
                data: function (searchTerm) {
                    return { query: searchTerm };
                },
                results: function (data) { 
                    return {results: data}; 
                }
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
        });

 });
```

I could not populate my drop-down and it seems i am unable to call my url:"/AddNewOpp/FetchItems" in the ajax part of the jquery .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

***VIEW:*** 
     You need to put an input element wih type="hidden" attribute.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CUSTOMERID, new { id = "CUSTOMERID", @class = " input-block-level  bigdrop", placeholder = "Search for customer" })
```

***CONTROLLER***: 
     Aim is getting data which you want to fill the dropdown with,  and return in json.

```
public JsonResult FetchItemsCustomer(string query)
        {
            List<CRM_CUSTOMERS> projectList = db.CRM_CUSTOMERS.Where(p => p.IS_VALID == 1 && p.NAME != null).ToList(); //fetch list of items from db table
            List<CRM_CUSTOMERS> resultProjectList = new List<CRM_CUSTOMERS>(); //create empty results list
            foreach (var item in projectList)
            {
                //if any item contains the query string
                if (item.NAME.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    resultProjectList.Add(item); //then add item to the results list
                }
            }
            //resultProjectList.Sort(delegate(Item c1, Item c2) { return c1.ItemName.CompareTo(c2.ItemName); }); //sort the results list alphabetically by ItemName
            var serialisedJsonProjects = from result in resultProjectList //serialise the results list into json
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             name = result.NAME, //each json object will have 
                                             id = result.ID      //these two variables [name, id]
                                         };
            return Json(serialisedJsonProjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //return the serialised results list
        }
```

***JQUERY AJAX PART:***

```
$("#CUSTOMERID").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 4,
        ajax: {
            url: "/AddNewOpp/FetchItemsCustomer/",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (searchTerm) {
                return { query: searchTerm };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return { results: data };
            }
        },
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            $("#addAsCustomer").fadeIn(1000);
            return "Aradığınız müşteri sistemde kayıtlı değil,\"Yeni Ekle\" butonuna tiklayiniz";
        },
        formatInputTooShort: function (input, min) {
            $("#addAsCustomer").fadeOut(500);
            var n = min - input.length; return "" + n + " karakter daha giriniz" + (n == 1 ? "" : "");
        },

        formatResult: contractFormatResult,
        formatSelection: contractFormatSelection,
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    });
```

Comment: great that you solved the problem, i am having some trouble too. first of all do you need to define the select2 dropdown anywhere or is this code enough, and second: after using your solved code i got the error contractFormatResult is not defined. it is in the script on almost the last line, do you define this somewhere?

Comment: Did you try with removing this line ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using below code in js file:

jquery:

```
function getEoOrgPositions() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/GetDataHandler/GetEoOrgPosition",
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: '1' },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    $('#selectListOrg')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", key)
                        .text(value));
                    options.push({ value: key, text: value });
                });
             }
        });
}
```

My controller name is GetDataHandler :

```
       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult GetEoOrgPosition(string action)
        {
            return Json(_db.GetEoOrgPosition(action), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Context DB:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetEoOrgPosition(string action)
    {
        var data = new DataTable();
      var postlist=new Dictionary<string, string>( );
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = string.Format(
                                      "select PosSysCode , PosParentSysCode , EOSysNum , PosName + ' : ' + PrsName + ' ' + PrsLastName as FullPostName " +
                                      "FROM EOOrgPosition " +
                                      "inner join EOPersons on EOOrgPosition.CA_Persons = EOPersons.CA_Persons " +
                                      "left outer join vwEOUsers usr on (usr.UsrPrsCode = EOPersons.PrsCode) and (usr.UsrState <> 'active') " +
                                      "WHERE usr.EOSysNum IN (select WhichCode from EOPermAssign WHERE OwnerCode = {0} AND Status = 4) order by FullPostName",
                                      action);

                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        da.Fill(data);
                        postlist =
                   data.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                       .ToDictionary(item => item["PosSysCode"].ToString(),
                                     item => item["FullPostName"].ToString());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return postlist;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please your action and view also ? Thanks

Comment: I edit my answer.Look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669459/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-calls-action-method-too-late) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002163/jquery-ajax-call-data-parameters-are-not-being-passed-to-mvc-controller-action)

Comment: Did you use select2 box ?